# On Centos (3.10.0-514.2.2.el7.x86_64), rdesktop command is not able to connect to Windows 2016 Server

Tags: windows, centos7, rhel6, windows-server-2016, rdesktop

I am using below command to connect to Windows Server 2016 but it is throwing below error

```
Command:
rdesktop <IP> -g 1100x600

Error
Autoselected keyboard map en-us
ERROR: recv: Connection reset by peer
```

In windows 2016 server, I have checked "Allow remote connection to this computer" and unchecked " Allow connections only from computers running Remote Desktop with Network Level Authentication". Also I corrected the Windows firewall setting and it allows Remote connection to Public and Private.
I am able to do telnet from the linux machine to the windows server via public IP. 
Can you please help me to connect to windows 2016 server via linux machine using rdesktop command